# Cannot correct php.ini error in Magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, php

Hello I'm using the latest magento source files from magento website. I've installed the files via directions on the support documentation of magento website and at the Readiness Check point i get the follwing errors:

> our PHP Version is 5.6.14, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0.
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be
>   removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please
>   open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If
>   you need more help please call your hosting provider.

all other php checks are correct.
[image: Rediness Check Results]

When I begin to debug the error with trying to find the php.ini file. I have:

1. Created the phpinfo.php page to determine where the php.ini file is located.

   I get this information [image: location of php.ini file]

***2. I CANNOT FIND THE PATH FOR /opt/php56/lib/php.ini***

Answer (score 1):

edit php.ini

find
always_populate_raw_post_data = On

change to 
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

close web page.. restart xampp or wamp

Comment: these files are on the server an im accessing via cpanel/ ftp and cannot find the file to edit or find the php.ini file.

Comment: Check where your ini file is loaded, its path by hitting the url of the server root

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the **.htaccess** file inside your magento root
2. Find the line `<IfModule mod_php5.c>` and add the lines below before `</IfModule>`

The point is the following lines should be between

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c> and </IfModule>
```

3. Insert these lines below in your .htaccess file and save the file and proceed with your installation.

   ```
    #########################################
    ## Turn off automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

    php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data off
   ```

If the above lines didnt work then try -1 instead of off

```
     ###########################################
     ## Turn off automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

     php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1
```

Please note, i assumed you use php5.x without FastCGI , incase of FAST CGI [follow this article](https://www.saotn.org/magento-20-php-ini-always_populate_raw_post_data-setting/)

Answer (score 1):

We created a new php.ini file on the root of server and edited the always_populate_raw_post_data -1 and now we can proceed further. THanks for the feedback and answers they did help me achieve the goal.

see our image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Search in php.ini and remove `;` from php_flag `always_populate_raw_post_data -1`

Restart server it will work :)